# Java: Extracting a specific REGEXP pattern out of a string

Tags: java, regex

How is it possible to extract only a time part of the form XX:YY out of a string?

For example - from a string like:

**sdhgjhdgsjdf12:34knvxjkvndf**, I would like to extract only **12:34**.

( The surrounding chars can be spaces too of course )

Of course I can find the semicolon and get two chars before and two chars after, but it is bahhhhhh.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this look-around based regex for your match:

```
(?<!\d)\d{2}:\d{2}(?!\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE5bM7/1)

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d{2}:\\d{2}(?!\\d)");
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<!\d)  # negative lookbehind to assert previous char is not a digit
\d{2}    # match exact 2 digits
:        # match a colon
\d{2}    # match exact 2 digits
(?!\d)   # negative lookahead to assert next char is not a digit
```

**Full Code:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d{2}:\\d{2}(?!\\d)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputString);

if (m.find()) {
    System.err.println("Time: " + m.group());
}
```

Comment: Looks great! But how can I extrat the time out of the string with that? Thank you!

Comment: Use `Matcher` class in Java and call `p.matcher` followed by `matcher.find` and `matcher.group` to get your value

Comment: Yes! I managed to find this solution already! thank you so much!

Comment: That's great, I've also provide full code in answer for reference.

Comment: Thank you... But I tried your expression on "18/02/2016 14:00" and it didn't match... Maybe I should have told you that it can be at the end of the string...

Comment: I understand now - the "natural" expression you gave me works great. But the code doesn't. I understand that you add backslashes to each original backslash to fit in Java. But I get "no match found"... :-(

Comment: An idea - You can try pad your string by adding a space at the end @dushkin, before running to fix that match an end of string issue.

Comment: https://ideone.com/2EzLIz - no space addition is necessary, lookarounds do not consume characters.

Comment: @micstr didn't help... :(